# How to get width of parent that is above in hierarchy of current parent

Tags: css

I've got my <<*main*>> in a wrapper that keeps it in one column in center of page. However I would like to have an <<*hr*>> tag between sections of it and I'd like it to span the entire width of the page. How can I do that?

Comment: Please post up the _minimum_ information (HTML, CSS, etc) needed to recreate the problem.

Comment: I think I explained it clearly enough

Comment: @VanillaSnake21 Seems quite unclear to me. Seems like you are asking two different questions in your title and body. I'm not certain if you want to have the `<hr>` tag get the width of a parent or the page itself.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it's the same thing, the parent is the page.

Comment: How you have something set up may not be how I set up something, which may not be how the next person sets it up. Knowing _exactly_ what you have eliminates the guess work and gets you answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rem`, or `px` to set its width. Don't use percentage.

You would have set the value of `rem` through trial and error. Keep in mind the devices that app would be used on, set the value accordingly.

Comment: Umm, I would rather not do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question to include a piece of code that shows what you have, because the answer may depend on how you are using the css in the wrapper to center the content.

For example, if you use padding to do it, this is probably what you are asking for:

```
.wrapper {
   padding: $padding;
}
hr {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% + 2 * $padding;
  left: -$padding;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 0 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main2 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

hr {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 80px);
  left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='main'></div>
  <hr>
  <div class='main2'></div>
  
</div>
```

--- Edit ---
By your comment, i understand that you have the wrapper with a max-width and margin-auto, then I would suggest to just remove that from the wrapper and apply margin and max-width to the main, and the hr will extend itself to the full width without extra changes.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
}

.main, .main2 {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.main {
  background-color: red;
}

.main2 {
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='main'></div>
  <hr>
  <div class='main2'></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: left and right margin on auto and max-width set to 1000

Comment: How can I have a preset padding on my page if I need to keep the column centered no matter the sizes of the window?

Comment: @VanillaSnake21 I edited my answer and added an option that fits your needs. Another suggestion may be to have the content centered by setting it to `display: inline-block;` and the parent with `text-align: center`. You can also take a look at [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Well yes I could obviously just split the main into a bunch of parts and turn the whole code into tag hell, with mains from 1 to 9, but is this really the best solution?

Comment: Is there a way I can get the width of the parent of a parent?

Comment: You can use absolute positioning, with widht:100%, Then the element will get the widht of the first parent with position other than static. Btw, I would still like to know how is that a tag hell. You already have (I assume) 9 tags, separated by hr's, can't you made those 9 tags the 'main'?. You can also use border-bottom property and you will have 8 less tags (hr) in your code.

Comment: @VanillaSnake21 You **must** post an example of your code so we stop imagining your layout and see exactly what you are working on and on what you need help.

Comment: not only would that require me to use the generic div instead of the main tag but this is just incredibly backward written code just to accommodate a  graphical element. I mean why would I sacrifice logical flow of a page to do this? And absolute coordinates are no good either, it would remove hr from the document flow.

Comment: You're asking too much for what you give.

Comment: <div id="wrapper">    <main> <div id="WelcomeSection" /> <div id="CurrentProjectsSection"/> <div id="TestimonialsSection"/> <div id ="AccreditationsSection"/> </main> </div>

Comment: wrapper {margin: 0, auto; max-width :1000px;}

Comment: were talking html not haskell, waste of time with these 'code' samples

Comment: 1. Waste of time is not giving code samples. If you give them from the start we would have saved time imagining what you had. I even gave you answer based on wrong assumptions (bad from me, I should have just ignored the question). 2. Not because you "don't want to sacrifice the page flow" for something you need/want, we can change the browser specs, some things are doable in some certain ways, for example, what you have can be made in the forms I already told you(sure i'm missing something), but you have to change some parts, and sacrifice others to get things to work as you need/want.

Comment: 3. You should update your question with the code sample, maybe someone else have **the answer** but need more info to know it, as others have already asked.

Comment: 4. You can extrapolate my answer (second part) to what you have: remove wrapper, set the max-widht and margin-auto to the divs inside the main (`main > div {margin: 0 auto; max-width :1000px;}`). No specific properties required in main. And I don't think you're sacrificing anything for it to work.

Comment: All right, I just imagined there was a more elegant solution to this than having to step in and out of centering code. But I'll have to go with it. Thank you.